# How to use a custom error page in a class context?

Tags: python, flask

Flask documentation [clearly explains](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers) how to create a custom error page via the [`errorhandler()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) decorator.

**How can I use custom pages when my Flask app is part of a class** as the decorator cannot be used with a method? An example:

```
import flask

class Webserver:
    def __init__(self):
        app = flask.Flask(__name__)
        app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=self.hello)
        app.run()

    def hello(self):
        return 'hello'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Webserver()
```

The usage of `add_url_rule()` bypasses the same problem for routing, is there an equivalent for `errorhandler()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an equivalent for registering error handlers directly, called [`app.register_error_handler()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.register_error_handler):

```
class Webserver:
    def __init__(self):
        app = flask.Flask(__name__)
        app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=self.hello)
        app.register_error_handler(404, self.not_found_handler)
        app.run()
```

Even so, the `errorhandler()` just needs to be passed the bound method. If you wanted to register a method as the handler for the `404 Not Found` HTTP code, for example, just create the decorator object for `404` and call that with the bound method as the argument:

```
class Webserver:
    def __init__(self):
        app = flask.Flask(__name__)
        app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=self.hello)
        app.errorhandler(404)(self.not_found_handler)
        app.run()
```

This works because all the `@app.errorhandler()` decorator does is register the callable, so the return value is the original callable still. You can ignore that here and only use it for the registration action.

The same would work for the `app.route()` decorator.

Comment: Is it enough to just use `404` in your example? I tried this in my example code and got a `werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404: Not Found`

Comment: @WoJ: The `errorhandler()` argument is either a HTTP code, or an exception, see the  [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler).

Comment: OK, I found the issue: the traceback was an internal one, the core problem was that my handler definition did not account for the parameter passed by  `register_error`, namely the error code. Thank you.